# jQuery Array problem

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, image-gallery

I am trying to create an array images to preload by getting each of the image link in the `rel` attributes.

I have on a page:

```
<div id="gallery_thumbs">
  <a><img src="images/image-1-thumb.jpg" rel="images/image-1.jpg" /></a>
  <a><img src="images/image-2-thumb.jpg" rel="images/image-2.jpg" /></a>
  <a><img src="images/image-3-thumb.jpg" rel="images/image-3.jpg" /></a>
  <a><img src="images/image-4-thumb.jpg" rel="images/image-4.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

When the page loads I need to get all the `rel` attributes in the `#gallery_thumbs a img` and append these to an array like so:

```
preload([ 'images/image-1.jpg', 'images/image-2.jpg', 'images/image-3.jpg', 'images/image-4.jpg']);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: for formatting, just highlight the section of code and click the `101010` button up top, it'll space it over 4 spaces...and markdown will format it nicely for you.  Click edit above to see how the formatting looks after I tweaked it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map function:

```
$("img").map(function(i,e) { return $(e).attr('rel');})
```

Comment: This seems to work but how would you convert the strings into a an array?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of the strings you want, like this:

```
var arr = $("#gallery_thumbs img").map(function() { 
            return $(this).attr("rel"); 
          }).get();
preload(arr);
```

---

An `<a>` without a name or `href` is invalid though, why not have the `href` to go the image you want (which would degrade gracefully), and prevent that action in JavaScript?  Your markup would look like this:

```
<div id="gallery_thumbs">
  <a href="images/image-1.jpg"><img src="images/image-1-thumb.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/image-2.jpg"><img src="images/image-2-thumb.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/image-3.jpg"><img src="images/image-3-thumb.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/image-4.jpg"><img src="images/image-4-thumb.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Making the script above simpler too:

```
var arr = $("#gallery_thumbs a").map(function() { return this.href; }).get();
preload(arr);
```

Comment: This returns undefined in Firefox??

Comment: @Chill - The first?  `rel` is an invalid attribute, so I'd *really* go with the second if possible.

Comment: I still can't seem to get the it to preload from the array,